# NullPointerException while calling a Soap webservice ValueWriter.writeBase64BinaryElem(ValueWriter.java:1158)

Tags: java, spring, web-services, exception, websphere

I have been investigating a JAX-WS webservice client issue for a day now. Its a weird experience where the exception is fired while sending the request to the servcie from the internal ibm class. I could see the connection to the service was successfully established, and the issue occurs while the binary marshalling.

We are in WAS 8.5.X in across all environments. This issue doesn't occur in my local server, but only in the dev environment server. I know I will have to check the IBM jar versions related to JAXB and JAXWS but I will have to prove the issue to the team so that they can look at the jar versions.

Do anyone of you have any clue what happens here?

**An Update - This issue occurs only in WAS 8.5.5.1 servers. I have tested with 8.5.5.2 and 8.5.5.0 wintout any issues. I see IBM fix packs addressing unmarshalling issues but nothing about marshalling.**

Exception below,

> org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsSoapFaultException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is
>   javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:557)
>     at
>   org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.invoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:541)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.getNewImportID(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.xxxxx.Utils.uploadDocuments(Utils.java:172)   at
>   com.xxxxx.Action.submitDocuments(Action.java:114)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
>     at com.xxxxx.Interceptors.intercept(Interceptors.java:90)   at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:314)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:558)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:608)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:985)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1074)
>     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862) Caused
>   by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1353)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMinimalMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitBareMinimalMethodMarshaller.java:442)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:626)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:566)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.getNewImportID(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
>   org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:580)
>     at
>   org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:554)
>     ... 77 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.marshal.impl.ValueWriter.writeBase64BinaryElem(ValueWriter.java:1158)
>     at
>   com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.marshal.impl.SerializationContext.writeBase64BinaryElementValue(SerializationContext.java:710)
>     at
>   com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.marshal.JAXB_Serialization_Root_Stub.write(com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.marshal.JAXB_Serialization_Root_Stub.java)
>     at
>   com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.marshal.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext$5.run(JAXBDSContext.java:1027)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.marshalByType(JAXBDSContext.java:921)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.marshal(JAXBDSContext.java:452)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.impl.JAXBBlockImpl._outputFromBO(JAXBBlockImpl.java:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl.outputTo(BlockImpl.java:371)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl.serialize(BlockImpl.java:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:781)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:967)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.writeMessage(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:3423)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.sendChunkedRequest(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:898)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.sendSOAPRequest(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:817)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.send(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:589)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPTransportSender.invoke(HTTPTransportSender.java:366)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:544)     at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:578)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:419)

```
... 85 more
```

Comment: Never mind. I nailed it. JAX-WS webservice in WAS 8.5.5.1 would not work with out JAXB marshalling fix pack. Hope it should be helpful to someone facing same kinda issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I nailed it. JAX-WS webservice in WAS 8.5.5.1 would not work with out JAXB marshalling fix pack. Hope it should be helpful to someone facing same kinda issue.